# How to determine if a string is of type Double or Long

Tags: java, regex, types

I have a ResultSet that i iterate over and i create a report like view (html).
The problem is that some columns return Long values (as a result of mathematical function in SQL).

Is there an easy way that I can identify this values by DataType?

Lets say i want to do something like this

```
String x = rs.getString(1);
if(MyUtilClass.isOfTypeLong(x)){
  //implement my bussiness logig
}
```

I have seen this post [How do you determine the type of data contained in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447583/how-do-you-determine-the-type-of-variable-a-string-is) . If there isn't anything better right now, I will proceed with the regEx solution.

Comment: This may be the answer you want: http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/jdbc/recipes/ResultSet-ColumnType.shtml

Comment: What does the resultset metadata say? i.e. in what type does mysql send you the data? rs.getMetadata().getColumnType? Read more here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html . Does it send it as a string, or long, or double directly?

Comment: `Object x = rs.getObject(1);` and then `instanceof BigDecimal` and others. As catch-all class `getBigDecimal(1)` is worth a thought.

Comment: Don't you know at compile time what datatype will be returned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you try [`Long.valueOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) to first parse it as a `Long`, and failing that parse it as a `Double` with [`Double.valueOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29)?

Both throw a [`NumberFormatException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) if the string cannot be parsed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String s1 = "1234567890";
    System.out.println(isParsableAsLong(s1));    // true
    System.out.println(isParsableAsDouble(s1));  // true

    final String s2 = "1234.56789";
    System.out.println(isParsableAsLong(s2));   // false
    System.out.println(isParsableAsDouble(s2)); // true
}

private static boolean isParsableAsLong(final String s) {
    try {
        Long.valueOf(s);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException) {
        return false;
    }
}

private static boolean isParsableAsDouble(final String s) {
    try {
        Double.valueOf(s);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If `.` can be used to differentiate then:

```
    String number  = "12345";
    if(number.indexOf(".")>=0){
        //decimal
        Double doubleValue = Double.valueOf(number);
    }else{
        Long longValue = Long.valueOf(number);
    }
```

With Exception Handling:

```
    String number  = "12345";
    //You may define two variables as Double & Long (as used in previous example)
    Number formattedNumber = null;

    try{
        if(number.indexOf(".")>=0){
            //decimal
            formattedNumber = Double.valueOf(number);
        }else{
            formattedNumber = Long.valueOf(number);
        }
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        System.out.println("Not a double or Long");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Long l=Long.parseLong(x);
```

and if it fails to parse then it will through exception in catch block try

```
Double=Double.parseDouble(x)
```

even then if exception occurrs it can not be parsed